# How to Switch login server(sandbox/other) in Salesforce Hybrid Mobile SDK on Android device without hardware menu button?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, salesforce-sdk-android, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

Using Salesforce Hybrid Mobile SDK, I am able to OAuth easily to production on Android devices.
I am trying to change login server to sandbox, which works fine on Android devices, where a hardware menu button is present, as it shows the following footer button bar, to change server. But on

[image]
[image]

But same option is not visible on Android devices without hardware menu buttons, usually Android apps show action bar like this one [image]

Here is what I see on Android device without hardware Menu button:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Mobile SDK v3 is available and it solves this problem. You need to upgrade forcedroid and other mobile sdk stuff via NPM to get that.

As shown in picture below, the login window now always shows the action bar and easy way to change server.

[image]

But ran into other issue, after upgrade on existing projects i.e.

```
"Uncaught module com.salesforce.plugin.oauth not found" - cordova.js:59
```

Apart from upgrading forcedroid, cordova, and manually copying latest of

```
cordova.force.js
forcetk.mobilesdk.js
```

from Salesforce shared lib on github (after doing pull on it). You need to include cordova.force.js in index.html script includes.

Thats it :) ﻿

Answer (score 0):

It's great news that it's fixed in v3.0... nice work.

If you're stuck using an older SDK (I am for a couple of projects I'm on) then this post details a very simple (and ugly-ish) work-around. http://bit.ly/custom_domain_sdk﻿